# Issue with installing geopandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.6, geopandas

I'm trying to install geopandas on my laptop, a Windows 10 version 1709 machine.

After executing the pip install geopandas command, I'm getting the message:

```
command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1.
```

I already tried to upgrade pip and setuptools, but still no success. I installed Python 3.6.

Comment: Is it the full traceback? Can you post complete error message from console?

Comment: command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in \temp\pip-build-xxx\shapely. There is also a WinError126

Comment: Can you provide the full output of the `pip install geopandas` command? It seems it tries to build shapely itself. Which might be explained by the fact that shapely does not provide binary wheels for Windows: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely. I would suggest trying to install from wheels from here: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely, or to use a different package manager like `conda`.

Comment: If you want shapely to build yourself, you also need the GEOS C library (not only the visual studio build tools from windows). The shapely installation instructions suggest indeed the use the wheels from Gohlke or conda as I mentioned above: https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project.html#built-distributions

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you got something like this error:

```
      File "C:\Users\Simon\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 848, in __init__
        raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(err)
    distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Simon\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-2vl7e6lb\pyproj\
```

That error appears because you need to compile the package yourself.  On Windows that requires build tools.

You just need to go to the link given to you in your error message and download [Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017).  Once you have done this, Try the installation command again.  It should now work.

You can also find out more information from [Windows Compilers](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers#Microsoft_Visual_C.2B-.2B-_14.0_standalone:_Build_Tools_for_Visual_Studio_2017_.28x86.2C_x64.2C_ARM.2C_ARM64.29)

Comment: @H.Baeten  What is the error before `command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1.`?  Also what version of setuptools do you have?

Answer (score 0):

Experiencing the same problem, the only thing that worked for me after having tried the various solutions suggested here -- I'm using Jupyter Notebook on Anaconda -- was installing it through the anaconda platform [Environments]; I hope this helps someone.