# I can't install fiona package in python

Tags: python, pip, installation, geopandas, fiona

I'm trying to pip install geopandas, everytime i try this error pops up:

```
Collecting fiona
  Using cached Fiona-1.8.13.post1.tar.gz (1.2 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\hp\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-r8dvuzzr\\fiona\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-r8dvuzzr\\fiona\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-cl_m3849'
         cwd: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r8dvuzzr\fiona\
    Complete output (1 lines):
    A GDAL API version must be specified. Provide a path to gdal-config using a GDAL_CONFIG environment variable or use a GDAL_VERSION environment variable.  
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I'm doing this in VSCode using Python 3.7.7.

How am i supposed to provide a path to gdal-config or whatever I am supposed to do to solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue with installing geopandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49772348/issue-with-installing-geopandas)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+GDAL+API+version+must+be+specified